# Scope of the order-theory tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, specific-question

I was really unsure about tagging [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305584/how-to-find-a-number-which-comes-just-after-0-5) question.
The misconception behind the OPs question lies in the area of [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) (not every order has a well-defined concept of a "successor") and he was obviously (inference from the naiveness) referring to [real-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-numbers) or [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers).

However, the original wording didn't realize that the question was regarding orders and the question asks about a *particular* property of a *particular* order The tag wiki features this:

> Questions about properties of orders, general or particular, may fit into this category

But that leaves me a little inconclusive. Looking at the questions tagged with [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) didn't shed any more light either. Is the question on-topic for [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I understand [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) tag, it would fit any question which is mainly concerned with partially ordered or linearly ordered sets. For such questions [relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relations) could also be suitable. (And sometimes [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory).) Tagging of questions about (partially) ordered sets was also briefly [discussed in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/tag-for-posets-and-preordered-sets) some time ago.

The question you link seems to be closely related to the notion of successor and existence of successor in a totally ordered sets. So, in my opinion, [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) seems like a good fit for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the reference :) That was my thought process as well but since I don't consider myself an expert of [tag:order-theory] by any means, I wanted to confirm by looking at the /tagged/ list - wich lead to my confusion.